# Python / Discord FFMPEG playing not a audio

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

I wanted to play an mp3 file in a voice channel, however, it gives me an error... I have already installed FFMPEG correctly on my computer.

My Code:

```
@bot.command()
async def joinandplay(ctx):
   song = os.path.isfile("musik.mp3")
   voice_channel = bot.get_channel(940326390857883648)
   vc = await voice_channel.connect()
   voice = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song)
   vc.play(voice)
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing `opuslib` and change your line like this?

Code:

`voice = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song)` to `voice = discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(song)`